# JSON API fail with " (double quote) in variable

Tags: php, json

When "descriptions" field has " (double quote) API is failing.

Image to check all parameter sent by users

[image]

Below code to get the data from posted JSON.

```
    //Clear newline and tab from the jason sent from opti
     $cleanJSON = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',file_get_contents("php://input")));
     $jason_value = json_decode($cleanJSON);
     $crm_id = $jason_value->data->crmId;
     $descriptions = $jason_value->data->descriptions;
```

I would like to remove " from any variable in the middle of main "".

descriptions = "I have to call at 2" pm,".

I do not have access to the program where the user enters the description where I can add validation don't allow ". \n.

Getting below string after conversion

```
{ "jwt": "eyJ0", "data": { "crmId": "15876047", "geoconceptAppointmentId": "15876","geoconceptCustomerId": "15876047","status": "Rejected","appointmentDateTime": "","firstName": "Nick Test","lastName": "PA","address": "9112 RUE Tom","city": "MONTREAL","state": "QC","zip": "H2N1T1","country": "CAN","phoneNumber1": "5148332222","phoneNumber2": "5148332222","email": "nbskgg@gmail.com","dateEntry": "2019-06-20 12:02","dateModify": "2019-06-20 12:02","preferredWayToContact": "","textMsgFlag": "Y","hearAboutUs": "Referral","perferredTime": "Anytime","descriptions": "I have to call at 2" pm","worklog": "This is the comment ","rejectReason": "Area | Region","referredByDC": "09999","referredByStoreUsername": "store215","assignedUsername": "","createdByUsername": "np","modifiedByUsername": "np","btgMarket": "Montreal"}}
```

Comment: You need to find out where that is coming from and have it fixed on that end. It's not a proper json, so it's not easily fixed.

Comment: Why do you need to "clean" the json? Are you getting invalid data? How the json is formatted should be quite irrelevant as long as there aren't any unescaped new lines in the values themselves.

Comment: @aynber, I do not have access to that program.

Comment: Then you need to contact whoever created that program and tell them the json they're creating is invalid.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, Yes sometimes I get new line, ", and tab in variables

Comment: Ouch. If they can pass data like that, I bet they are building it manual or similar. In that case, you're in for a fun time. That would mean that there could popup more issues along the way. Instead of trying to match their mistakes in your code, tell them to give you proper data instead. Trying to solve issues like this can be _extremely_ hard (and sometimes impossible to automate).

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, they are using java or something and already reported them but they said might be fixed in the new update of the software in 4 to 6 months. :(

Answer (score 0):

It 's maybe help you from php.net

```
<?php
$a = array('<foo>',"'bar'",'"baz"','&blong&', "\xc3\xa9");

echo "Normal: ",  json_encode($a), "\n";
echo "Tags: ",    json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_TAG), "\n";
echo "Apos: ",    json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_APOS), "\n";
echo "Quot: ",    json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_QUOT), "\n";
echo "Amp: ",     json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_AMP), "\n";
echo "Unicode: ", json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), "\n";
echo "All: ",     json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), "\n\n";

$b = array();

echo "Empty array output as array: ", json_encode($b), "\n";
echo "Empty array output as object: ", json_encode($b, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT), "\n\n";

$c = array(array(1,2,3));

echo "Non-associative array output as array: ", json_encode($c), "\n";
echo "Non-associative array output as object: ", json_encode($c, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT), "\n\n";

$d = array('foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'long');

echo "Associative array always output as object: ", json_encode($d), "\n";
echo "Associative array always output as object: ", json_encode($d, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT), "\n\n";
```

Comment: This answer is all about `json_encode()`. The OP get'st the JSON data from an external source (out of their control) and are having issues _decoding_ it, not _encoding_ it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Regex that try to detect unescaped quotes

```
(?<![ ,\\])"(?![:,\}])
```

It looks after all quotes that are

- Not preceded by a space (first key)
- Not preceded by a comma (all other keys)
- Not preceded by a backslah (if they escaped some of the quotes)
- Not followed by a double-punt (end of a key)
- Not followed by a comma (end of value)
- Not followed by } (end of the data)

Then you can escape manually the quotes of your pseudo-JSON string with `preg_replace()`

```
 $regex = '/(?<![ ,\\\\])"(?![:,\\}])/' ;
 $json = preg_replace($regex, '\"', $string);
```

Obviously, this code is not robust at all (if the client send `I have to call at 2", pm` the regex will fail to detect the unescaped quote), and the real solution is to fix the JSON itself, but hopefully that can help you to process most of the data until the fix.